# <title> appears / disappears / reappears between elements that are in the same <a> link. Just Chrome?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, cross-browser

Similar Q has been asked before, but in a much more specific environment, and hasn't yet been answered.

My Q is a general one about the title-tag, which I'm using to ensure the visitor knows when a link is going to open in a NEW window. The issue occurs when the cursor moves over parts of the ???link-text???

... Just realized I don't know the name for the 'text' (in my case) between the  tag's opening-tag and closing-tag.   w3.org is not much help, it says:

> Anchors The format of an anchor is as follows
>   ...
>
> The text between the opening tag and the closing tag is either the
> start or destination (or both) of a link.

So, for now I'll call it the 'text' ;)

```
<a href="..." title="Opens in new window">TEXT</a>
```

The code above is no problem - the 'title' displays OK.

```
<a href="..." title="Opens in new window"><span>MORE </span> TEXT</a>
```

The above, causes (on Chrome) the 'title' to appear (when the cursor is over "MORE") - to disappear&reappear (when on the space between the words) - then again disappear&reappear (when over "TEXT").
*Nb. You will need to move the cursor slowly to see the effect fully.*

Is it just Chrome?
Can it be solved by HTML &/or CSS?

Here's my test code:

```
<style>
.box1  {
    display:block;
    width:400px;
    height:100px ;
    background:yellow;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.linkSymbol {
    padding-right:1em;
}</style>


<div class="box1"><a  href="www.google.com" title="Opens in New Page">Link to somewhere</a><p>'Title', when it eventually displays after x secs, stays on when hovering&moving the cursor on the link</p></div>
<div class="box1"><a  href="www.google.com" title="Opens in New Page"><span>&#128279; </span>Link to somewhere</a><p>'Title' appears & disappears between the symbol & the link text</p></div>

<div class="box1"><a href="www.google.com" title="Opens in New Page"><span class="linkSymbol">&#128279;</span>Link to somewhere</a><p>'Title' appears & disappears between symbol and the space, then again between the space and the link text</p>
<p>Even though they are parts of the SAME link</p></div>
```

Comment: IE11 does NOT seem to have the same problem.

Comment: Display: block - doesn't solve it either.